VS22: Break on all std exceptions
For an attached debugger to break on exception, I need to add to Exception Settings> C++ Exeptions all std exceptions, e.g., std::exception, std::runtime_error.
Is there an easier way to specify that it should break on std::exception and any exception that inherits it?
How can I set it as the default list?

In the Exception Settings > C++ Exceptions list, there is an entry called <All C++ Exceptions not in this list>. Check this. If you also remove all other exceptions that derive from std::exception from the list under C++ Exceptions (including the default entry for std::exception), you mostly get what you want. "Mostly", because it will of course also break on all exceptions that do not derive from std::exception (except the ones that are in the list). But hopefully these are rare.

Another idea: To stop execution really just on std::exception and derived exceptions, one could put a breakpoint on the std::exception constructors. I.e. in the Breakpoints list in VS > New > Function breakpoint > enter std::exception::exception and select C++ as language. That works at least if optimizations are disabled (i.e. in debug), where the std::exception constructors are not inlined in the derived class's constructor.
Maybe it is also an option to put a breakpoint on __std_exception_destroy() instead. This is an internal function that gets called from the destructor of std::exception. It has the advantage that it is not defined in the header, and thus cannot be inlined in derived classes by the compiler, meaning that the breakpoint gets hit more reliably.

Thanks, but obviously, I saw this option, and it's not rare (e.g., matlab API keeps throwing stuff as normal operation). I'd like to add only these exceptions.

@ZoharLevi Can't you just add these Matlab exceptions then to the list without activating them, meaning that VS then ignores those exceptions, but still breaks on all others?

As I recall, there were too many.

@ZoharLevi I don't think that what you want is possible with the exception settings. However, another idea would be to put a breakpoint on the std::exception constructors. (Breakpoints list in VS > New > Function breakpoint > enter std::exception::exception and select C++ as language.) That works at least in modules built in debug, where the std::exception constructors are not inlined in the derived class's constructor. Or maybe a breakpoint on __std_exception_destroy(), which gets called in the destructor of std::exception and is never inlined?

Nice ideas. Still, I'll be looking for something easier. If there isn't such, then maybe they should consider improving VS.

You can create a suggestion ticket on developercommunity to suggest the improvement. Actually, I found this ticket which asked for the same thing, but it was closed because the original poster never answered.

I added information to the ticket. Thanks.
